# how to find the ratio of two group by outputs in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have to calculate the ratio between no. of restaurants by kind of cuisine per borough for restaurants db.
For this i am grouping by borough and getting counts of restaurants for denominator and by doing match and group by to get borough count with respect to cuisine.

using query:
dict2= []

```
a={"$facet":{T:[{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$borough","total" : { "$sum" :1 } } }],TT:[{ "$match" : { "cuisine" : "American " } },{"$bucket":{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$borough","total" : { "$sum" :1 } } }}]}
dict2.append(a)
```

and this is run in python using pipeline technique.This results in syntax error at dict2.append(a).What could be missing here.

Comment: `$divide` shouldb what you need.  What query did you try?

Comment: i intend to divde output of     command0 = { "$group" : { "_id" : "$borough","total" : { "$sum" :1 } } }
with     command2 = { "$match" : { "cuisine" : "American " } } and
   command3 = { "$group" : { "_id" : "$borough", "totalC" : { "$sum" :1 } } } i.e i want totalC/total . I understand that its not possible if i do it in a single pipeline?. Is there a way to do it with mongo db command  using aggregate command. I tried this: { "$project": { "_id":1,"totalC":1, "workdays": { "$divide": [ "$totalC","$total"  ] } } }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how `totalC` in

```
command3 = { "$group" : { "_id" : "$borough", "totalC" : { "$sum" :1 } } }
```

is different from `total` in

```
command0 = { "$group" : { "_id" : "$borough","total" : { "$sum" :1 } } }
```

I think what you're looking for is to first count:
- total restaurants
- restaurants by cuisine
- restaurants by borough
- restaurants by borough and cuisine

and then perform some arithmetic with those numbers.

A `$facet` stage might get you started:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$facet:{
    borough:[
      {$group:{_id:{borough:"$borough",cuisine:"$cuisine"}, count:{$sum:1}}},
      {$group:{_id:"$_id.borough",cuisine:{$push:{cuisine:"$_id.cuisine",count:"$count"}}, count:{$sum:"$count"}}}
        ]
    cuisine:[{$group:{_id:"$cuisine",count:{$sum:1}}},
    total:[{$count:"$count"}]
  }},
])
```

This should give you a single document containing 3 arrays, similar to:

```
{
  borough:[{_id:"boroughname", count:xx, cuisine:[{_id:"cuisinename", count:xx},...]},...]
  cuisine:[{_id:"cuisinename", count:xx},...],
  total:[{count:xxx}]
}
```

Comment: I am looking for is the total restaurants grouped by borough, and then restaurants by borough for  filter to a cuisine say X and then divide no.of restaurants by borough for a specific cuisine by total restaurants grouped by borough. TotalC in my code was for no.of restaurants by borough for a specific cuisine. I am not sure how can i divide these values using $divide because if i use 'total restaurants grouped by borough' my further aggregated query can't be executed.

Comment: That aggregation will give you the total by borough, the total by cuisine by borough, the total by cuisine and the total.  You can use $filter to look at a subset of the elements in either array, then $unwind and/or $divide the values

Comment: Thanks for your help Joe!